# Why I can't use document.getElementById() after render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

- index.html

```html
<body>
        
        <div id="root">
           heyyy boi
        </div>   
          
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

- app.js

```
const heading = React.createElement(
    "h1",
    {
        
    },
    "Heading"
);
//console.log(heading);
// document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "Hey Buddy!"
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(heading);
// document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "Hey Buddy!"
```

When I tried to do this(document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "Hey Buddy!") after and before render method it is showing me my default value that I put in html file.
And I was expecting new value but it's not coming why so ?

I am new to react and doing some stuff by myself to learn small small things. Anyone please help me.

Comment: You should not use `getElementById` nor `innerHTML` in React. What are you tryin to do?

Comment: const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")); - >   In this line it's working that's why I was trying to do after render and before render also.

Comment: But that doesn;t make any sense. Let React handle the DOM, don't use JS to go beyond React.

Comment: One of the driving principles of React is to avoid dealing with the DOM manually. Trying to do both - use React and use `innerHTML` makes about as much sense as using fork to eat soup. It can *sort of* work. In some circumstances. Like, if the soup is particularly thick. Or if you employ some other methods of eating the soup in addition to a fork. But whatever the case the fork is just not the correct tool for the job. Everything else that makes it somewhat OK sometimes is a workaround.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot use **document.getElementById()** after the render method is because the element you are trying to select has not been added to the DOM yet. When you call **ReactDOM.render()**, React creates a **virtual DOM** representation of the component you passed in, but it does not immediately update the real DOM. The real DOM is only updated after the next paint cycle.

If you try to call document.getElementById() before the next paint cycle, the element you are trying to select will not exist in the DOM yet, and document.getElementById() will return null.